# How to configure Tomcat7 with two SSL

Tags: tomcat

I currently have a domain that works with SSL on Tomcat. I want to add a second domain running the same application on the same Tomcat server with SSL, but I was not successful in this. How can I run the same application with an SSL certificate on different domains?

Comment: Are you trying to use the same SSL cert for both the domains or two different certs? You might find some guidance [here](https://medium.com/@mashrur123/a-step-by-step-guide-to-securing-a-tomcat-server-with-letsencrypt-ssl-certificate-65cd26290b70)

Comment: No I got two SSL cert for two domains. Also I have added Connector tag for two cert files. <Connector port="443" ...
            keystoreFile="file1"
            keystorePass="pass1"
            .../>
<Connector port="443" ...
            keystoreFile="file2"
            keystorePass="pass2"
            .../>

Comment: What is 'two SSL'? Do you mean two SSL *certiificates*?

Comment: Yes I mean two SSL certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Tomcat to use multiple connectors, with different IP addresses and certificates. i.e

```
<Connector 
       port="8443" maxThreads="200" address="x.x.x.x"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="keystore1.jks" keystorePass="..."
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
<Connector 
       port="8443" maxThreads="200" address="x.x.x.x"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="keystore2.jks" keystorePass="..."
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are the required addresses local addresses? Could you explain?

Comment: It depends on your requirement. If you want to same IP both connector then make sure that port should be different in both connectors

Comment: I don't want the ports to be different. Because both domains are for users. @Pandurang

Comment: then you can use different IP addresses for each SSL connector.

Answer (score 0):

You can try differentiating with ports# i.e 15443 , 18443

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I try different ports. Could you explain?